# HELP to install PSPP - Terminal not working

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, updates, gnome-terminal

I am new to Linux and need to install PSPP ( Linux free version of Social Statistcs -PSSP) for college. When I try to install it on the terminal it doesnt work.

This is what it says:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_micahflee_ppa_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_micahflee_ppa_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_micahflee_ppa_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_micahflee_ppa_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fGB
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I did also try to install discord chat to find help and this is what it said when I tried to download it, in case it helps to solve the main issue with the terminal

[image]

Any help, please?

Comment: Please [edit] to add the output of `sudo apt update` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`. Don't add images of the outputs, paste them as text and code format them instead. Read [ask] and [How to format the question](/help/formatting)

Comment: Are you running Linux Mint 16? 

Comment: @matigo There is a Linux Mint icon in the bottom left-hand corner, so I think the OP is using Mint, making this question off-topic

Comment: Hi matigo! Linux Mint 18

Comment: Oh I see..is there any group chat to help with Linux Mint? @matigo

Comment: @ValleCurly Not a group chat, but Stack Exchange (the company that runs this site) has a site dedicated to other versions of Linux, including Linux Mint. It is called [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), so you could ask there.